# Facebook like button counter/referral

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want people to be able to like facebook X from my page by using a simple like button.

At the same time, I want to show how many likes/referrals there has already been from other people visiting and liking page X from my site.

Facebook's developer page says I have to add data-ref somewhere to this code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your Website Title</title>
    <!-- You can use open graph tags to customize link previews.
    Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
  <meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
  <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
  <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
  <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <!-- Your like button code -->
  <div class="fb-like" 
    data-href="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" 
    data-layout="standard" 
    data-action="like" 
    data-show-faces="true">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Facebook's explanation is this:
ref
data-ref
A label for tracking referrals which must be less than 50 characters and can contain alphanumeric characters and some punctuation (currently +/=-.:_). See the FAQ for more details.
None

And yes I have seen the "See the FAQ for more details." but I shoot me I can't figure it out.

Comment: The documentation mentions this in the same table where it lists other parameters, such as the href, layout, action and show-faces. Now when you look at where those are placed in the code above - then you should probably be able to guess where this ref parameter belongs as well, hm?

Comment: Hehe.. Yeah, I guessed as much, and I've tried putting it in below: data-ref="" - And then putting one of their parameters in like "Home" - But nothing happens :-/ So I figured I was prooobably a code dummy! :-P

Comment: Well what do you expect to happen? This just causes additional tracking parameters to be added to your URL, when someone follows the link that resulted from a user liking your page and at the same time posting this to Facebook. It does nothing else. If you want that to translate into actual numbers - then you have to do that in your analytics software.

Comment: I expected the number of clicks/like on the button to be shown in a little bubble next to the button as I've seen different places on the weeeeb :-P

Comment: So you just want the button to show the number of likes the item has received? That has absolute nothing to do with referrals. Chose a different button layout.

Comment: Well, as I've wrote a couple of times, I'm a bit of a noob, so that was me trying to explain what I wanted - And when you write "Chose a different button layout" - My question is, how? Where? I've been searching for this function, as I wrote, for hours now!

Comment: As I said, just choose a different layout in the configurator - box_count or button_count.

Comment: box_count or button_count - count the amounts of like the specifik page has, it doesn't show the number of clicks/likes sent from my website :-/

Comment: There is no built-in way to display those numbers. You would have to implement that yourself. But I suspect you do not really want the referral functionality here, because as I explained that affects what data is send back to your site when a user follows a link _from_ Facebook. If you want to count the number of likes the target received directly from _your_ like button, then you can subscribe to the event of a like being created via the JS SDK - but you still have to do the counting, and getting that count displayed somewhere yourself.

Comment: Well, I've seen the function all over the web - There are even plugins to exactly that, but it's in floating sidebars and that sort of thing, instead of on one specific page. I guess I'm not gonna find the answer here, but thanks for trying anyway.